# One button and a list view layout problem

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-listview

So I am trying to create a program that tracks gps coordinates and then display them real time in a list view on the side of my main screen, the layout looks as follows:

```
_______
|{} |LV|
|   |  |
|   |  |
|   |  |
|___|__|
```

{} = button
LV = list view scrolling vertical

What I have in on create is:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundleIn) {
        super.onCreate(bundleIn);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        retrieveLocationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);
        bottomList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        AllLocals.add("1");
        bottomList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getApplicationContext(), R.id.simple_text, AllLocals));

        //viewCollectedData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.view_lat_lon_data);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Location>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,AllLocals));
```

XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Get Local" 
            android:id="@+id/retrieve_location_button" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
          <TextView android:id="@+id/simple_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />
          <ListView android:id="@+id/myListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The program is failing, and I am not sure what is incorrect here is the log file:

```
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{geolocation.test/geolocation.test.GeoLocationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-07 15:37:20.301: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-07 15:37:20.301: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-07 15:37:20.301: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-07 15:37:20.301: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     
at geolocation.test.GeoLocationActivity.onCreate(GeoLocationActivity.java:47)
09-07 15:37:20.301: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-07 15:37:20.301: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-07 15:37:20.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     ... 11 more
```

Apprently there is a null exception at the following line:

```
bottomList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getApplicationContext(), R.id.simple_text, AllLocals));
```

I have no clue why. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: show me ur manifest file

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="geolocation.test"<br /> --- the names match and i can run the program if i remove the viewlist, thus i am assuming the issue is there

Comment: u have a semi-column after the android namespace ? 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ; ????

Comment: for the null exception show mee the error

Comment: no, no that is stackoverflow adds that when I copy paste for some reason

Comment: if i uncomment this line: bottomList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getApplicationContext(), R.id.simple_text, AllLocals)); --- then everything works fine so the issue is that my listview is setup incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok try this
 `bottomList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AllLocals));`  and make sure that u initialize the AllLocals before u call this method

`AllLocals = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: this is not the problem in my case

Comment: ok try this 
bottomList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AllLocals));
tell me what is the result and make sure that u initialize the AllLocals before u call this method 
AllLocals = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: I can't my reputation is not high enough, sorry